# how to implement error handling on store in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm working on existing codebase and my task is to implement error handling in my update Chart but not really sure how to implement correctly since I'm using store management so I would be really appreciated if I can get any suggestion or help on how I should implement error handling in store.

I did something like this and tested it by providing to the wrong api route in my ChartService.ts file but I didn't get the error message and it always saying it "has been saved" no matter if I give the right api route or wrong api route for updating chart.

The problem I have right now is, It's not giving me error snackbar message even when there is errors in api or network.

```
import {Store} from '@ngrx/store';

  saveClick(){
    try
    {
      this.store.dispatch(updateChart({chart: this.chart}));
      this.snackbar.open("Changes to \"" + this.chart.name + "\" has been saved", "", { duration: 2500 });
    }
    catch(error)
    {
      this.snackbar.open("Error has occurred. Could not update Chart", "", { duration: 2500 });
    }
  }
```

Chart.effets.ts

```
    updateChart$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ChartActionTypes.UpdateChart),
        exhaustMap((props: { chart: Chart }) => this.chartService.updateChart(props.chart)//this.getChart(props)
            .pipe(
                // tap(c => console.log('TAPPY TAP', c)),
                map(chart => {
                    return chartLoaded({ chart: chart })
                }),
                catchError(() => EMPTY)
            ),
        )
    )
    )
```

HTML

```
    <button color="primary" mat-flat-button (click)="saveClick()" [disabled]="this.chart.isPublished">Save</button>
```

It's not gonna run on but I uploaded all the code for this component in stackblitz hoping someone can help me by looking at the code. thanks https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ncbmb4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pretty close:

- Your dispatch of update is fine
- Your chartLoaded is fine
- Your catchError is wrong

Notice the way you dispatched an action to update your store with the new data, you need to do the same when you get an error.

```
catchError((error: any, effect: Observable<Action>) => effect.pipe(startWith(chartUpdateError({ error }))))
```

So this new action is going to set the error in the store using the reducer. Now to know if an error happened, you need a selector that check for what you just updated in your store which means your saveClick() doesnt handle any of that. You either subscribe to the selector in your ts file or in your html depending on what you are looking to do. I cant really help you with the syntax because I dont know what your reducer/action/selector look like.

Comment: Hi thank you for some tips but by anychance can you look at all the code for this components in stackblitz and help me https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ncbmb4 . it's not going to run but just hoping you can see all the code and you might able to help me. thanks

Comment: You need to provide the reducer/action/state/selector

Comment: ok...I just did but I'm not really sure if I uploaded the right file so please let me know if you need more. thank you

Comment: here it is, there are multiple way to monitor the errors but I just did it in a subscription. I might have missed some import but thats basically what it should look like: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-weytt4?file=src%2Fapp%2FChart%20Reducer%2Fchart.reducer.ts

Comment: And I added around the code I added(not explanaing anything) just to make it easier to see the changes

Comment: Hi thank you so much for providing me this. Quick question, I'm getting error on chartUpdateError    in Chart.Effects.TS file and wondering if that supposed to be updateChartError?.

Comment: Yes, most likely

Comment: Also I saw you put this.subscription.add with my snackbar so wondering what is going on. I thought I need to put it in my Save button function and how my save button will know how to display the snackbar.

Comment: The button has no idea what's going on, only the state knows if the request worked or not which is why you need to listen to the changes of the selector

Comment: oh ok.. I believed I added all your code in my project but some reason It's not working yet. I'm still getting "has been saved" and endless 404 errors on my Network tab.

Comment: I'm not sure my testing is the right way but I'm testing it by adding extra route like this in /TESTING in my http post "  return this.http.post<Chart(`${environment.api.chart}/charts/TESTING/${chart.guid}`, chart).pipe(first()); "

Comment: and I'm not sure why even success snackbar is not showing anymore when I update successfully. any idea?. thanks

Comment: Well debug the effect and check the error value, if it's undefined you can always make the state property a boolean and set it manually

Comment: @AaseZi I modified the effect, I missed something yesterday

Comment: Hi thank you but please can you tell me which line you modified cuz I'm seeing exactly the same in Chart.Effect.TS file. thanks

Comment: Oh ok...I'm guessing you modified the Reducer.TS file since I'm not seeing any changes on Effects.TS file. I just added that code in Reducer.TS file but sadly I'm still getting the same result ( no snackbar message display and  endless 404 errors on network tab) :(

Comment: oh ok.. just saw the changes. Now I didn't get endless 404 errors anymore and I only get only one errors now but not sure why it's still not showing the snackbar. I imported selectChartUpdateError from Reducer in my Chart.Details TS ngOnit but the snackbar still not showing.

Comment: Your 404s are completely unrelated to what I told you to do and could be part of a bigger problem. I'm afraid I can't do more since the stackblitz isn't working and I can't debug for you. I already answered the question and made the changes to your code now I think you need to figure out the rest or ask a new specific question!

Comment: Last thing, check if the catchError is reached with an actual error, if it's not then just assign it to true

Comment: oh ok... I understand and thank you so much for your help. I'm learning so I really do appreciated it.