# How to handle stroe dispatch error Ngrx inside component

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have something like this

```
  public addNewFilter(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new FilterActions.CreateFilter(this.addFilterForm.value));
    this.activeModal.close();
  }
```

The problem I have is that i dont want to action  **this.activeModal.close();** if **store.dispatch** return error, any idea how can i manage this? I know it can be handled inside effect, but I have modal here in component?

Answer (score 0):

This goes against the NgRx design. The state of the modal should be dependent on the state of the application, and listen to this state via an observable. You said yourself, it can be handled inside an effect.

I'd recommend reading https://medium.com/@gausmann.simon/error-handling-in-ngrx-and-ngrx-effects-6d331c517bcc

and

[how to implement error handling on store in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62546582/how-to-implement-error-handling-on-store-in-angular)

Answer (score 0):

you need to track the state of the action dispatched on separate state and close the modal on that state change to success only. check my answer here for the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68363069/how-to-close-matdialogbox-or-any-div-when-api-is-successful-in-ngxs-state/68368095#68368095) , stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4ofc3q?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Any chance you have a StackBlitz example that UNIT Tests this Action/Effects? I'm trying to figure out how to write a UNIT TEST for this type of stuff.

Comment: @edjm unfortunately no, Actually I never unit test the state management, but it should be straight forward tests with mocking the state and test for the component (no worries about the actions or effects) and unit test the effect without considering the component.